# Angular 2: Class Properties Not Updating On params retrieval

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this code

```
testFunction() {

    let params = <any>{};

    if (this.searchTerm) {
        params.search = this.searchTerm;
    }

    // change the URL
    this.router.navigate(['job-search'], {queryParams: params, replaceUrl: true});

    // same component, so just parse URL
    this.route
        .queryParams
        .subscribe(params => {
            this.searchTerm = 'search' in params ? params['search'] : '';
        });

    console.log('With Search Term: ' + this.searchTerm);

    this.jobService.search(
        this.pageNumber,
        this.pageSize,
        this.searchTerm).subscribe(
            response => {
                if (response.success) {
                    this.jobs = jobs.data;
                    this.paginatorData.total = jobs.data.total;
                    this.paginatorData.per_page = jobs.data.per_page;
                }
            }, error => {}
    );
}
```

triggered by a button:

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm jobs-table-search" style="width: 150px;">
                    <input id="search-box" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" type="text" name="table_search" 
                           class="form-control pull-right" placeholder="Search" (keyup.enter)="parseRequest()">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" (click)="testFunction()">
                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

my problem:

1. Enter 'sample term', click button, this.searchTerm does not change
2. click button again, this.searchTerm changes
3. delete 'sample term', set to empty string, press button, this.searchTerm remains 'sample term'
4. press button again, this.searchTerm now empty string

it works when I wrap the service function in a `setTimeout`

What's wrong? (sorry, quite new to Angular 2)

Comment: Move the route subscription to the constructor. Where have you declared `searchTerm:string` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that comes to mind is that you're subscribing to the route's query parameters **after** you're navigating, and inside a function.

Usually, one would subscribe to route changes once, in the constructor of the component, and define what should happen on change there.

The way your code is structured now leads to multiple subscriptions to route param's changes, I would start by moving this to the constructor of the component.